# Как одним стилем описать содержимое дочерних элементов Layout в Android приложении

Tags: android, вёрстка, android-studio, android-style

Добрый день. Имеется ли возможность в стилях Android описать оформление дочерних элементов, например как это можно сделать в стандартном CSS? Например, у меня есть активити, в которой расположены элементы CardView, которые в свою очередь содержат различные элементы - это может быть TextView, Button, ImageView и тд. Хотелось бы создать стиль, который бы описывал все эти элементы и при необходимости смены оформления (например, через скрипт), достаточно было бы прописать новый стиль у элемента CardView, и все вложенные бы поменяли свой внешний вид, на описанный мною. Такое возможно в стилях Android? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно для таких целей создают свой собственный элемент.
Например есть некий `CardView` содержащий `TextView`, `Button`, `ImageView`.
Для этого нужно создать сначала отдельный xml layout с разметкой, содержащей все указанные выше элементы.
Затем просто создать класс типа

```
public class MyCustomCardView extends CardView {

    private TextView myTextView;

    public MyCustomCardView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public MyCustomCardView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_custom_card_view, this);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        //аналогичным образом можно добавить остальные элементы
    }
}
```

Ну, соответственно можно добавить свои атрибуты, добавить методы для установки значений, листенеры и так далее.

Более подробная инфа в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Довольно неудобно, если сравнивать с обычным html и css, где все можно решить классами, но раз так принято, значит  придется делать, что-то подобное.

Comment: @GlWhitefoot, Кастомизировать классы стоит если Вам не хватает функционала, и стандартных возможностей: [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: @woesss ну в данном случае либо инклудить каждый раз один и тот же layout и каждый раз инициализировать все внутренние элементы, что нарушит принцип DRY, либо так. Просто стилями тут не обойдешься.